# Disable Auto-Commit in Oracle Application Express

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am in an online class learning PL/SQL, and I'm using a student version of Application Express (https://iacademy.oracle.com/ords/f?p=4550:1:0:::::).  Some of the assignments I'm given require me to disable auto-commit before attempting them.  It is implied that there is a checkbox to do this, but I cannot find one:

[image: APEX Screenshot]

Is there a way to disable auto-commit in APEX?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

1. Login to APEX as admin (means into INTERNAL worksapce).
2. Go to Manage Instance => Feature Configuration => SQL Workshop => Set Enable Transactional SQL Commands to Yes

[image: APEX admin interface]

3. Logout, login as standart user

[image: APEX user inetrface]

4. Autocommit checkbox will be available.
5. You should notice:

> Select Yes to enable transactional SQL commands for the entire Oracle Application Express instance. Enabling this feature permits SQL Command Processor users to issue multiple SQL commands within the same physical database transaction.
>
> When you select Yes, an Autocommit check box appears on the SQL Command Processor page. By default, this option is set to No.

Comment: i think op doesnt have access to INTERNAL workspace.

Answer (score -2):

Changing Auto-Commit for a Database Type

```
Open Tools->Tool Properties,
Select the Database tab,
Expand the node for the database type, e.g. Oracle,
Select the Transaction category,
Uncheck the Auto Commit checkbox.
```

Changing Auto-Commit for a Connection

```
Double-click the connection node in the Databases tab tree to open an Object View tab,
Select the Properties tab,
Select the Transaction category under the node for the database type, e.g. Oracle,
Uncheck the Auto Commit checkbox.
```

Changing Auto-Commit for an SQL Commander tab

```
Use the SQL Commander->Turn On/Off Auto Commit toggle item, or,
Use the corresponding toggle button to the right in the SQL Commander toolbar.
```

Changing Auto-Commit for a Statement Block

You can use the @set autocommit command in a script to enable or disable auto commit for different blocks:

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I cannot find any of the tabs/windows/buttons you mentioned.  I am using a student version of APEX (https://iacademy.oracle.com/ords/f?p=4550:1:0:::::) and I am not a DBA.  Do I need the DBA to disable autocommit, or is there something else I need to do?