# How do I fix this error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

Got this error while trying to enter values for 2 different tables on Oracle APEX and need help figuring out where I went wrong. I'm not sure if it's because I made a typo somewhere or it's because I'm just doing it all wrong.

```
INSERT INTO copy_student_course_details (grade, student_id, course_id)
VALUES ('A', 720, 190);

INSERT INTO copy_student_course_details (grade, student_id, course_id)
        VALUES ('A', 750, 192);

INSERT INTO copy_student_course_details (grade, student_id, course_id)
    VALUES ('B', 760, 190);

INSERT INTO copy_student_course_details (grade, student_id, course_id)
    VALUES ('A', 770, 194);

INSERT INTO copy_student_course_details (grade, student_id, course_id)
    VALUES ('B', 720, 193);

INSERT INTO copy_student_course_details (grade, student_id, course_id)
    VALUES ('C', 730, 191);

INSERT INTO copy_student_course_details (grade, student_id, course_id)
    VALUES ('F', 740, 195);

INSERT INTO copy_student_course_details (grade, student_id, course_id)
    VALUES ('C', 760, 192);

INSERT INTO copy_student_course_details (grade, student_id, course_id)
    VALUES ('D', 770, 192);

INSERT INTO copy_student_course_details (grade, student_id, course_id)
    VALUES ('F', 770, 193);

INSERT INTO copy_faculty_course_details (contact_hours, faculty_id, course_id)
    VALUES (3, 800, 192);

INSERT INTO copy_faculty_course_details (contact_hours, faculty_id, course_id)
    VALUES (4, 800, 193);

INSERT INTO copy_faculty_course_details (contact_hours, faculty_id, course_id)
    VALUES (5, 800, 190);

INSERT INTO copy_faculty_course_details (contact_hours, faculty_id, course_id)
    VALUES (3, 800, 191);

INSERT INTO copy_faculty_course_details (contact_hours, faculty_id, course_id)
    VALUES (4, 810, 194);

INSERT INTO copy_faculty_course_details (contact_hours, faculty_id, course_id)
    VALUES (5, 810, 195);
```

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in what you've posted so are you sure the error comes from the above statements? Try running each individually until you find the problem

Comment: Run each statement one at a time and you'll know where Oracle has an issue.

Comment: I ran each individually and it worked so I don't what the issue was before. Thank you to you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In APEX you have a SQL commands editor, and a script runner.

A script can contain multiple commands, and they are run one after the other.  In the SQL commands window, we run a *single* command, so after your first insert we are expecting to be done, and hence, when we find more content...we think you first command was not properly ended.

So either save this as a script and run it as a script, or you can run the entire insert as a PLSQL anonymous block, ie

```
begin
  INSERT INTO copy_student_course_details (grade, student_id, course_id)
VALUES ('A', 720, 190);

INSERT INTO copy_student_course_details (grade, student_id, course_id)
        VALUES ('A', 750, 192);
 ...
...
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome answer. Worked for me!

Remember that in an Apex IDE (SQL Workshop / SQL Commands) auto-commit is default when you install the environment or using OCI (Autonomous) or apex.oracle.com;
If you wanna change it, see here:
[Disable Auto-Commit in Oracle Application Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598235/disable-auto-commit-in-oracle-application-express#:%7E:%20text=Open%20Tools%2D%3ETool%20Pr,erties%2C,Uncheck%20the%20Auto%20Commit%20checkbox)